# Actual table column width is unequal with set number

Tags: tables, columns, lengths

I want to create a table with fixed column lengths like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|p{1cm}|p{2cm}|p{3cm}|}
    \hline
    1 cm  & 2 cm  & 3 cm  \\
    \hline 
\end{tabular}

Table with actual widths

\begin{tabular}{|p{0.56cm}|p{1.56cm}|p{2.56cm}|}
    \hline
    1 cm  & 2 cm  & 3 cm  \\
    \hline 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But column lengths are not the exact number, that I set. So I found the shift to make column with lengths, that I want.

Why this is happening and how I can automate the process of getting right value?

Comment: The argument of the `p` columns specifies the textwidth inside the cells, not the total width with padding around the text.

Comment: If you just for fun remove all other spaces `\begin{tabular}{|@{}p{1cm}@{}|@{}p{2cm}@{}|@{}p{3cm}@{}|}` you can see the effect

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\setlength\arrayrulewidth{2pt}
\begin{tabular}{|p{\dimexpr1cm-2\tabcolsep}
                |p{\dimexpr2cm-2\tabcolsep}
                |p{\dimexpr3cm-2\tabcolsep}|}
    \hline
    1 cm  & 2 cm  & 3 cm  \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\rule{6cm}{2pt}
\end{document}
```

make absolute width of cells as you like to have. `rule` is comparison of the table width.

Answer (score 2):

Almost the same as @Zarko's answer, except reducing the (fine) length of the line separating columns... and a introducing a customized macro:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array, calc}

\newlength{\lw}
\setlength{\lw}{2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{| p{1cm-\lw} | p{2cm-\lw} | p{3cm-\lw} |}
        \hline
        1 cm  & 2 cm  & 3 cm  \\
        \hline 
\end{tabular}
Table with actual widths
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.56cm}|p{1.56cm}|p{2.56cm}|}
        \hline
        1 cm  & 2 cm  & 3 cm  \\
        \hline 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

producing :

[image]